# left join tables for many relation data

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have two table. first for insert sliders options and second for insert relation slide for sliders.

slider table:

```
| id |  title   | status |  slider_options   |
---------------------------------------------
|  1 | slider1 |   1    | [{"speed":"5000"}]
```

slides table

```
| id | slider_id |           image        | content | order
------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |     1     | upload/images/xxx.jpg  |  NULL   |   1
|  2 |     1     | upload/images/yyy.jpg  |  NULL   |   2
|  3 |     1     | upload/images/zzz.jpg  |  NULL   |   3
```

now in update page I need to show data for sliders and relation slide.

```
public function getSliderData(int $id)
{
    return $this->db->table('sliders')
        ->select('sliders.*, slides.id as slide_id, slides.image as image, slides.order as order')
        ->join('slides', 'slides.slider_id = sliders.id', 'left')
        ->where('sliders.id', $id)
        ->get()
        ->getResultObject();
}
```

output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => slider1
            [slider_options] => [{"speed":5000}]
            [status] => 1
            [slide_id] => 1
            [image] => uploads/images/xxx.jpg
            [order] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => slider1
            [slider_options] => [{"speed":5000}]
            [status] => 1
            [slide_id] => 1
            [image] => uploads/images/yyy.jpg
            [order] => 2
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => slider1
            [slider_options] => [{"speed":5000}]
            [status] => 1
            [slide_id] => 1
            [image] => uploads/images/zzz.jpg
            [order] => 3
        )

)
```

in output result i see three array Object and sliders data(id, title, slider_options, status) for each slide. i need to show sliders data and show relation slides data(images data) into sliders(for update page). how do can i fix this?

Comment: this would happen to any join not only left. But i didn't understand what you want to achieve. I thought you are searching for group by https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: This is not clear. What does "show sliders data and show relation slides data(images data) into sliders(for update page)" mean? Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution & a user knows how to use it. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best solution to handle such situation.. Try this.

```
public function getSliderData(int $id)
{
    $data = $this->db->table('sliders')->where('id',$id)->get()->result();

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $value->slides = $this->db->table('slides')->where('slider_id',$value->id)->get()->result();

    }

    return $data;
}
```